# How to keep my bitcoin safe when I move my bcash?

Tags: security, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

I had some bitcoin during the coinsplit, so now I have bcash that I want to move.

When I send bcash there is a risk that someone copies the transactions and uses it to steal my bitcoin. Most people recommend moving the bitcoin to a new adress for this. this is not practical for me right now, will it work to just move my bcash to a new adress instead before I send them or will this also allow an attacker to copy the transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bcash transactions cannot be replayed on the Bitcoin network, and vice versa, Bitcoin transactions cannot be replayed on the Bcash network. This is called 2-way replay protection. In Bcash's case, it's implemented by the mandatory use of a sighash flag that's invalid for a Bitcoin transaction.

Comment: This is not what I read in all the tutorials? Am I stupid or is there widespread misconseption about this?

Comment: 2-way replay protection was added very late before BCash's hard fork so some tutorials may be out of date.

Comment: Can you cite any sources? Mostly for 2-way replay protection and from your comment that it was implemented late. Thank you.

Comment: The pull request introducing the 2-way replay protection was merged into the code base on Jul 26th, while the fork happened on Aug 1st. See https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/pull/30